# Username expansion in sudoers file command possible?

Tags: sudoers

I have the following in my sudoers file :

```
User_Alias DU=%domain\ users
DU ALL = NOPASSWD:NOEXEC: /sbin/mount.cifs \\\\* /home/* -o sec=krb5\,* ,/bin/umount -t cifs /home/*
```

This works, users who are in the right group, and have a Kerberos ticket can mount their shares somewhere in their home.

But right now, **any** user can mount cifs shares in **any** directory under /home (because of the `/home/*`), and thus annoy their fellow users.

It would be a lot better if I would be able to change that to e.g. `/home/$username`, where `$username` is the name of calling user.

Is there a way to do this within the sudoers file ?

Otherwise I will have to create wrappers to limit the locations people can mount and unmount.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer, but I have not found anything usable. AFAIK it is not possible, because the sudoers file is plain text and not interpreted in any way. So the $-expansion for variables is a shell feature, but for the sudo program it's just \$username. A special syntax to declare a variable in the sudoers file does not exist, at least I have not found it so far.

A workaround would be to put your mount command into a script file and put that script into the sudoers file. Remove the write permissions for other users (chmod o-w scriptfile) and you should be good to go.